# WIrecloud behind apache and 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: fiware-wirecloud

I followed the basic installation in Wirecloud, and it works fine with the IP:Port in the browser. But when I try to put Wirecloud behind apache, it only charges some parts or makes the requests to some paths.

Here is my apache configuration:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias myserver.com
ServerName myserver.com
        <Directory /opt/wirecloud_instance/wirecloud_instance>
                <Files "wsgi.py">
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        ### Wirecloud ###                                                                                                                                                                                 
        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        WSGIDaemonProcess wirecloud python-path=/opt/wirecloud_instance user=wirecloud group=wirecloud
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/wirecloud_instance/wirecloud_instance/wsgi.py
        <Location />
                WSGIProcessGroup wirecloud
        </Location>

        Alias /static /opt/wirecloud_instance/static
        <Location "/static">
                SetHandler None
                Require all granted
                <IfModule mod_expires.c>
                        ExpiresActive On
                        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
                </IfModule>
                <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                        Header append Cache-Control "public"
                </IfModule>
        </Location>
        <Location "/static/cache">
                Require all granted
                <IfModule mod_expires.c>
                        ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 years"
                </IfModule>
        </Location>
 <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /mashup http://localhost:8087/


</VirtualHost>
```

Of course, Wirecloud is running in port 8087.

When I access wirecloud by the IP:Port, I can see in the log the following:

```
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1615
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:17] "GET /api/i18n/js_catalogue?language=es&v= HTTP/1.1" 200 15778
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:17] "GET /static/cache/css/8b10fb9ee986.css HTTP/1.1" 200 131167
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:17] "GET /static/cache/js/3574aebf19e5.js HTTP/1.1" 200 839375
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:17] "GET /static/images/logos/header.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6872
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:17] "GET /api/preferences/platform HTTP/1.1" 200 2
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:17] "GET /api/workspaces HTTP/1.1" 200 2
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:17] "GET /api/context HTTP/1.1" 200 595
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:17] "GET /static/fonts/opensans-bold-webfont.woff?69f4b4a30f27 HTTP/1.1" 200 63564
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:17] "GET /static/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff?69f4b4a30f27 HTTP/1.1" 200 63712
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:17] "GET /api/theme/wirecloud.defaulttheme?v=79224cfb9381f0db5a2ccf7ed2399e60978657cf HTTP/1.1" 200 1974
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:17] "GET /static/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1&69f4b4a30f27 HTTP/1.1" 200 43572
```

But if I access via apache, I only get:

```
[21/Dec/2015 02:09:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1615
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

I changed the proxy configuration to:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
ServerAlias myserver.com
ServerName myserver.com
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8087/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8087/
```